# PHP does not appear to warn me when I try to instantiate a non-existent class

Tags: php, debugging

I am using PHP5.3 namespaced classes. A common mistake is not getting the namespaces right (Absolute vs relative eg. \App\Models\Something vs Models\Something vs \Something). I commonly use PDO in my classes so that PHP tries to look in `\App\PDO` for example

I already have

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'ON');
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL | E_STRICT');
```

I notice sometimes when I am doing

```
$user = new User(); // when User should be located \App\User or App\User as I am in the root namespace, PHP does not trigger errors ... just give me a blank screen ...
```

Comment: Have you tried `ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1 );` and `error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT );` instead of your 2nd line?

Answer (score 1):

Both your lines are wrong:

```
ini_set('display_errors', true);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

The values shouldn't be in quotes.

Answer (score 0):

The single quotes in the second argument are wrong. It is being evaluated as 0.

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 'E_ALL | E_STRICT');

// same as:

ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
```

See [this page](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) for some valid examples of what you could pass as the second argument.

Once you fix that you will get:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Foo' not found
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should be like this:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('error_reporting', E_ALL | E_STRICT);
```

Furthermore, confirm that you are allowed to change php settings via `ini_set()`, or not, because you might think you are changing `display_errors` and `error_reporting`, but you might not be allowed to. That is, although your code executes, the parser does not take into account your settings.